# bazel build error "Server terminated abruptly (error code: 2, error message: Stream removed)"

Tags: bazel

"build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH="C:\Users\foem9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" mediapipe\examples\desktop\hello_world"
When using this command

Loading:
Fetching repository @llvm-raw; starting 55s
Fetching C:/users/foem9/_bazel_foem9/3vmcl3ou/external/llvm-raw; Extracting 1c154bd755153b5c6ada4bbed58facf23f6abffc.tar.gz 55s
Server terminated abruptly (error code: 2, error message: 'Stream removed', log file: 'c:\users\foem9_bazel_foem9\3vmcl3ou\server\jvm.out')

This error occurs.

There is nothing in jvm.out

Please help me

bazel version: 6.1.1
os:windows 10

Even if you use the 'bazel clean','--jobs=1' command, the problem persists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @foem, Have you tried using ```-- local_ ram_ Resources = 20000``` to limit the memory size to 20GB. Usually this is error raises when insufficient memory.